# Converting IN to Nested Joins

Tags: sql, join

I am struggling to use joins for this query:

```
select count(*) 
from t1
where t1.col1 not in (select distinct t2.colA 
                      from t2 
                      where t2.colB in (select distinct t3.XXcol 
                                        from t3)
                     )
```

This query works fine, but when I try to use joins:

```
select count(*) 
from t1 
inner join (t2 
inner join t3 on t2.colB = t3.XXcol) on t1.col1 != t2.colA
```

The results are different. I am not sure what I am missing here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `!=` is not equivalent to `not in`.

Comment: the main question is why want to do that?

Comment: Is there exist any universally accepted rational to NOT do it @eshirvana?

Why could be because of someone a learner, or something related to perf optimisation or trying to solve a bigger puzzle asking a simplified piece.

Comment: yes, this : “if it works, don’t touch it”.

Comment: The query works, but it does not work for some other reasons when connected with a few other aspects.

Comment: “if it works, don’t touch it”: acceptable for a tradie who comes to fix a plumbing and says, hey nothing broken, it all works.

Not acceptable for the architect who is looking for new ways to improve on their next project and exploring options :)

Comment: True, that's why it's a good idea to explain your intentions in your question and provide as much details. see my answer , hopefully it's helpful

Comment: "The results are different" is not very specific and if you analysed that further you may come up with some reasons on your own. One of the first differences is that joins will cause double counting if for example there are duplicate values in `colA` or `colB`. It's be easier to help if you included sample data to reproduce (this would need to include any duplicate data that may be causing the problem). Again, in the process of generating this repro, you'll probably solve your own problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure if joining will help you with the performance (if not worsening it) if this is your concern, but here is how you can implement that query using joins :

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT t2.colA
    FROM t2
    JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT XXcol
        FROM t3
    ) AS t3
    ON t2.colB = t3.XXcol
) AS t2
ON t1.col1 = t2.colA
WHERE t2.colA IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks.

Believe my trial query was missing two things, first to output the outcome of join (AS t2, AS t3) and then use that in the next comparator.

Another one, != is not same as NOT IN.